# MySQL 5.7 wrong results on sort / subquery

Tags: sorting, mysql-5.7

Very strange results in MySQL 5.7 (specifically 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 ).

I suspect this could be a bug in MySQL.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_grids_1`;
CREATE TABLE `test_grids_1` (
  `unq_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `var_fld` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `test_grids_1` VALUES
  (1,4500),
  (2,6000);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_grid_dtl_1`;
CREATE TABLE `test_grid_dtl_1` (
  `dtl_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unq_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `dtl_var` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT '0.00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `test_grid_dtl_1` VALUES
  (1,1,2.00),
  (2,1,2.40),
  (3,2,2.30);


SELECT
  ( g.calc_var * d.dtl_var ) new_var,
  g.calc_var
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    unq_id,
    IF ( var_fld  > 5000, ( 1 / var_fld ) , 5000 ) calc_var
  FROM
    test_grids_1
  ) g
INNER JOIN
  test_grid_dtl_1 d
    ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id;

+--------------+----------+
| new_var      | calc_var |
+--------------+----------+
| 10000.000000 |     5000 |
| 12000.000000 |     5000 |
|     0.000383 |   0.0002 |
+--------------+----------+

SELECT
  ( g.calc_var * d.dtl_var ) new_var,
  g.calc_var
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    unq_id,
    IF ( var_fld  > 5000, ( 1 / var_fld ) , 5000 ) calc_var
  FROM
    test_grids_1
  ) g
INNER JOIN
  test_grid_dtl_1 d
    ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY
  1;

+--------------+----------+
| new_var      | calc_var |
+--------------+----------+
|     0.000383 |   0.0002 |
| 10000.000000 |  99.9999 |
| 12000.000000 |  99.9999 |
+--------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When the sort is included it causes the returned values for certain criteria to be completely incorrect.

Values that are expected to be 5000 are suddenly 99.9999.

If anyone could please check and confirm similar behaviour on other 5.7 installations, it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What's the OS and version? What's the version of MySQL 5.7 (use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"` to get the version info)?

Comment: MySQL : 5.7 (specifically 5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 )."


OS : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: If I get to install a 16.04LTS with MySQL this weekend, I'll try to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**What's going on?**

The query is being bit by implicit casting by MySQL with joining and ordering.

**Solution**

Let's solve the problem first and then discuss how we got there. Notice the change of `1/var_fld` to `1.0/var_fld` and `5000` to `5000.0`.

```
SELECT g.calc_var * d.dtl_var as new_var, g.calc_var
FROM (
  SELECT unq_id, IF (var_fld > 5000, 1.0/var_fld, 5000.0) calc_var
  FROM test_grids_1
) g
INNER JOIN test_grid_dtl_1 d ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY 1

+---------------+------------+
| new_var       | calc_var   |
+---------------+------------+
|     0.0003833 |    0.00017 |
| 10000.0000000 | 5000.00000 |
| 12000.0000000 | 5000.00000 |
+---------------+------------+
```

You could re-write the query slight differently as well by using `cast`. Notice that I have included the hexadecimal value in the last column. It will be useful as you read on:

```
SELECT g.calc_var * d.dtl_var as new_var, g.calc_var, hex(g.calc_var) as hcalc_var
FROM (
  SELECT unq_id, IF (var_fld > 5000, cast(1/var_fld as decimal(15,5)), 5000.0) calc_var
  FROM test_grids_1
) g
INNER JOIN test_grid_dtl_1 d ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY 1

+---------------+------------+-----------+
| new_var       | calc_var   | hcalc_var |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
|     0.0003910 |    0.00017 | 0         |
| 10000.0000000 | 5000.00000 | 1388      |
| 12000.0000000 | 5000.00000 | 1388      |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Other solution**

Notice the replacement of `if` with `case` statement.

```
SELECT g.calc_var * d.dtl_var as new_var, g.calc_var
FROM (
  SELECT unq_id, case when var_fld > 5000 then 1/var_fld else 5000 end calc_var
  FROM test_grids_1
) g
INNER JOIN test_grid_dtl_1 d ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY 1

+--------------+-----------+
| new_var      | calc_var  |
+--------------+-----------+
|     0.000383 |    0.0002 |
| 10000.000000 | 5000.0000 |
| 12000.000000 | 5000.0000 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Notice how `case` statement didn't need any kind of casting to achieve almost the same result. However, to get to the exact same result as the first query, you'd have to do something like this -

**Yet another one**

Notice the `1.0/var_fld` and `5000.0` along with `cast` instead of `if`

```
SELECT g.calc_var * d.dtl_var as new_var, g.calc_var
FROM (
  SELECT unq_id, case when var_fld > 5000 then 1.0/var_fld else 5000.0 end calc_var
  FROM test_grids_1
) g
INNER JOIN test_grid_dtl_1 d ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY 1
```

**How did this come to highlight?**

Let's look at the original query; I've added a new field `hex(g.calc_var)` that is a hexadecimal representation of `g.calc_var`.

```
SELECT g.calc_var * d.dtl_var as new_var, g.calc_var, hex(g.calc_var) as hcalc_var
FROM (
  SELECT unq_id, IF (var_fld > 5000, 1/var_fld, 5000) calc_var
  FROM test_grids_1
) g
INNER JOIN test_grid_dtl_1 d ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY 1

+--------------+----------+-----------+
| new_var      | calc_var | hcalc_var |
+--------------+----------+-----------+
|     0.000383 |   0.0002 | 0         |
| 10000.000000 |  99.9999 | 1388      |
| 12000.000000 |  99.9999 | 1388      |
+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

**Compare the results with the very first query in the solution part**

```
SELECT g.calc_var * d.dtl_var as new_var, g.calc_var, hex(g.calc_var) as hcalc_var
FROM (
  SELECT unq_id, IF (var_fld > 5000, 1.0/var_fld, 5000.0) calc_var
  FROM test_grids_1
) g
INNER JOIN test_grid_dtl_1 d ON d.unq_id = g.unq_id
ORDER BY 1

+---------------+------------+-----------+
| new_var       | calc_var   | hcalc_var |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
|     0.0003833 |    0.00017 | 0         |
| 10000.0000000 | 5000.00000 | 1388      |
| 12000.0000000 | 5000.00000 | 1388      |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

Notice that the hex value is exactly the same in both the queries but the decimal values are different.

**How can 5000 end up as 99.9999?**

```
select cast(5000 as decimal(6,4)) as test;
+---------+
| test    |
+---------+
| 99.9999 |
+---------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'test' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Like that! When 5000 is cast to a decimal with length 6 including 4 decimals, the result is the maximum that will fit decimal(6,4). Ouch.

In this case a warning is thrown, which is good. One could catch it during testing. However, the query in question does not throw any warning. And that's not good.

**This leads to multiple questions**

- Why is casting happening correctly without `order by`?
- What in the `order by` is causing casting to happen the way we noticed?
- Why is `case...end` showing better results than `if(...)` even when no casting is done?
- Why is warning not thrown when casting like this is done?

You might want to put a bug report into MySQL folks. <strike>I don't have latest MariaDB installed so I can't say if this issue exists in MariaDB also.</strike> I got curious and installed 10.0.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. It appears the same issue is in MariaDB 10.0.25 also.

**Is this preventable?**

Yes. Whenever dealing with int to float/double/decimal, cast implicitly to get predictable results. I still expect MySQL to look into this corner case. If someone comes across documentation that explains this behavior, please add a comment to this answer so that I can educate myself.

Comment: Super response @zedfocus !!! Thanks for your very insightful answer, and I do agree that we need to inform MySQL. I'll raise a bug report with them.

Comment: What boggles my mind, and what screams **BUG** to me is the fact that this does not happen ( in my original examples) when the resultset is **not** sorted. Even if **All values** are supposed to be 5000, they are still 'cast' to result in 99.999 when sorted.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It appears to be a bug. It's a behavior that's quite hard to explain.

Comment: If you end up putting an issue on MySQL/MariaDB's issue tracker, could you please put the link here? I'd love to follow the issue and see the underlying cause. If you would like me to enter a bug, I can certainly do that

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for filing the bug report. If the answer above helped solve your immediate problem, feel free to mark it as accepted and put closure to your question, or feel free to wait for more answers.

Comment: @zedfocus - unfortunately, even though it does solve this very simple example, I fear that an entire system's worth of SQL is now in question. What would the proper follow up with MySQL be, as there has been no further response?

Comment: This is indeed a serious bug from MySQL and Shane Bester has acknowledged that it is a serious bug. Shane's a top technical support engineering with Oracle. I suspect that Product Managers make the call on which bug gets prioritized and released. So, while you wait for an answer, you could tweet at-mysql to bring attention to them. You could post to dba.stackexchange.com and see if users closely related to MySQL can impact their decision to fix it. Above all - always cast your fractions.